# I am struggling to understand and something in shaders

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I am watching thechernoproject tutorials on youtube for opengl and in the writing a shader in opengl episode he defines where the start of the position attribute is in the shader using the line:

```
layout(location = 0) in vec4 positions;
```

but my question is, why does he need to do this because surely when he previously used glVertexAttribPointer like this:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(float) * 2, 0);
```

So here he specifies how to read the buffer including the first position attribute index so why does he need to also specify it in the shader like he has above?

You can see all this code at 23:22 in the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71BLZwRGUJE&index=7&list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2

Answer (score 4):

> So here he specifies how to read the buffer including the first position attribute index so why does he need to also specify it in the shader like he has above?

Specify what in the shader, exactly? That the value is a 4-element vector? Well, there's no requirement that the corresponding type specified by the shader attribute is the exact same as that provided by the VAO. You can pass [integers which can get converted to floats via normalization or just "casting"](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Format). And so forth.

As you can see from your example, the number of components specified in the shader doesn't even have to match the number provided by the array. Your array sends 2 components for this attribute, but the shader takes 4. And that's *fine*; the last two values in the corresponding attribute will be 0 and 1.

Are you talking about that the name `position` maps to attribute 0? Well, how else is the system going to know that the array elements read from attribute 0 go into a variable named `position`. 0 means nothing to the system except an index; without the `layout(location` part, the system couldn't tell where to send the data read from the array.

Lastly and most importantly of all... `glVertexAttribPointer` modifies the vertex array object, *not* the shader. So how is the linked program supposed to know any of this stuff if its stored in some other object? How would you write to multiply the position from the array by a matrix if you don't assign some name in the shader to it?

No, every piece of information in that shader needs to be there. It is not redundant.

Comment: Ok thanks but also, how does the shader access the buffer in the first place because there is no buffer that actually ever gets provided to the shader

Comment: @adamtheguy762: The shader doesn't "access the buffer" at all. Vertex attributes are *provided* to the shader by the system.

Comment: ok but then if you have loads of buffers, how does the system know to provide the right buffer to the shader

Comment: @adamtheguy762: Because [you told it do](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification). That's what `glVertexAttribPointer` *does*. This is the entire purpose of VAOs.

Comment: also what is the pupose of in vec4 position

Comment: @adamtheguy762: I've told you the purpose of it in this answer. If you have further questions, the Ask Question button is the right thing to use. But do try to use your available resources to work it out for yourself. And stop watching bad video tutorials.